# Need somebody/something doing

Tags: meaning, sentence-structure

I just saw this usage and it confused me a little. Is it a appropriate  usage?

> I don't ***need Monty Hall ruining*** my place of work when Monty Hall
>   has already ruined my home life. (Brooklyn nine nine, tv-series)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is appropriate, at least colloquially.

The use of the word "need" is used to give more emphasis to how disliked the circumstance is in contrast to "want".  Compare:

> I don't want this happening right now!
>
> I don't need this happening right now!
>
> I **really** don't need this happening right now!

Comment: Yep, it's a common construction, e.g. *"I don't **need** you telling me I should ask my boss for more money.  I already know I should, but it's not as easy as you think."*

Comment: So can I use this form in different situations? For example : "I need you doing this job?"

Comment: + I have one more question: Is there a difference in meaning in the following alternatives? "I don't need Monty Hall (to be ruining or ruin) my place of work when Monty Hall has already ruined my home life. "

Comment: @TalhaÖzden In the first question, I believe "I need you _to_ _be_ doing this job" is arguably more natural, although "I need you doing this job" is also valid and means the same thing.

In the second question, similarly, "I don't need Monty Hall ruining" means the same as "I don't need Monty Hall to be ruining". "I don't need Monty Hall ruin" doesn't sound natural, but "I don't need Monty Hall _to_ ruin" sounds fine.

The sentence using _ruining_ implies that he is currently in the process of causing ruin. Using _to_ _ruin_ implies that he has not yet ruined anything.